# How to output even column indices of a 2D array and perform calculations on them in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

When I first put the loop iteration over a 2D array in reversed order (iterating first over columns and then the rows) with the braces after the second loop, it outputs the array as a transpose of the original.  But it doesn't output anything after I put any condition or a mathematical function in place.

I'm trying to output the elements which have even column indices only. I had previously solved this to print all columns for even rows only.

```
//outputs the sum, average, STD of even column indices and any row indices
if ( choice == 30 )
{
    {
        int sum = 0, c = 0;
        float avg, total = 0,std;
        cout << "the even column indices elements:" << endl;
        for( j=0; j < m; j++ )
        {
            for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
                if ( i % 2 == 0 )
                {
                    sum = sum + a[i][j];
                    c++;
                    cout << a[i][j] << endl;
                }
        }
        avg = float(sum / c);
        cout << "the sum of even columns:" << sum << endl;
        cout << "the average of even columns:" << avg << endl;
        for ( j = 0; j < m; j++ )
        {
            for( i=0; i < n; i++ )
                if ( i % 2 == 0 )
                {
                    total = total + ( a[i][j] * avg ) * ( a[i][j] - avg );
                    std = float( total / c );
                }
        }
        cout << "the STD of even columns:" << std << endl;

        // here is the output of the maximum and minimum of even columns elements
        int max = -999, min = 1000;
        for( j = 0;j < m; j++ )
        {
            for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
                if( i % 2 == 0 )
                {
                    if ( a[i][j] > max )
                        max = a[i][j];
                    if ( a[i][j] < min )
                        min = a[i][j];
                }
        }
        cout << "and their max value:" << max << endl;
        cout << "and their min value:" << min << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: **What exactly** _'doesn't work'_ please??

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems; though in truth I'm not sure whether these will impact your final problem. I'm hoping instead that these simplifications might instead shed light on the real problem and prevent you from introducing other problems while adding print statements and debugging.

**First Thought**
More just an optimization and simplification
Your idea to reuse the even row solution is good thinking, except that its much faster to stay row major.  (I'll leave it as an exercise for you or someone else to provide a reference to why row-major is faster as there are countless demo's of this on SO)  While the logic is similar its going to outperform your code immensely as the numbers of elements increase

```
for ( int row = 0; row < num_rows; row++ ) {
    for ( column = 0; column < num_cols; col+=2 ) { //notice increment by 2
        //do stuff to 2darray[row][column]
    }

    //another way
    for ( column = 0; column < num_cols; col++ ) {
        if ( columns % 2 != 0 ) {
            continue;
        }
        //do stuff to 2darray[row][column]
    }
}
```

**Second Thought**
If the `max` value ends up being less than -999 or the min is greater than 1000 then your code won't work.  Look up `limits.h` and use numeric limits for your type instead.
Why? If every value you read is < -999 as in say they were all -2000 the max will still report as -999.  Invert this to understand the problem with you min logic.

**Third Thought**
Again this is purely performance bound, and shouldn't impact the final answer being right or wrong.
You don't need to make multiple passes over your array to do this stuff.  You can do all the work in one pass.  You iterate over your 2D array 3 times, you only need to go through it once, you can make all your calculations in that one pass.

Comment: Regarding your statement "_Your if statements aren't getting executed because of issues with braces_", the braces you added have nothing to do with the `if` statements being executed.  The outer `if` statement will be executed regardless of the braces.  The inner `if` statements will be executed if `i` is even as well since they are enclosed within the outer `if` statement scope.  The braces you added are purely aesthetic in this case.

Comment: @Void you're right, my eyes skipped over the  `if ( i%2 == 0) {` which enloses them both and does pick them up.  Removing it.

Answer (score 0):

the thing about the max being assigned as -999, max is meant to check the maximum values, and min is checking the minimum values, so its suppose to ask at each position if the column indices if even then if it is, its asking if the greatest value (which are usually positive)
bigger than -999, and if they would be less than 1000, and so on.. until i get maximums and minimums, because -2000 is actually smaller than -999 so if i entered that, its suppose to be kept in minimum not max ^_^

Comment: But in that case the max isn't `-999`, the max is `-2000`. The minimum is also `-2000`.  Think about it at a higher level for a moment: What is the max and min of the set (-2000, -2000, -2000, -2000)? 
Also keep in mind, that this should be a comment on my answer and not a new answer :-)